# How to change value of row if doesn't match the row above in a function applied to a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows

```
structure(list(chr = 1, leftPos = 240000, OC_AH_026C.res = 0, 
    OC_AH_026C.1.res = 0, OC_AH_026C.2.res = 0, OC_AH_026T.res = 0, 
    OC_AH_058T.res = 0, OC_AH_084C.res = 0, OC_AH_084T.res = 0, 
    OC_AH_086C.res = 0, OC_AH_086C.1.res = 0, OC_AH_086C.2.res = 0, 
    OC_AH_086C.3.res = 0, OC_AH_086T.res = 0, OC_AH_088C.res = 0, 
    OC_AH_088T.res = 0, OC_AH_094C.res = 0, OC_AH_094C.1.res = 0, 
    OC_AH_094C.2.res = 0, OC_AH_094C.3.res = 0, OC_AH_094C.4.res = 0, 
    OC_AH_094C.5.res = 0, OC_AH_094C.6.res = 0, OC_AH_094C.7.res = 0, 
    OC_AH_094T.res = 0, OC_AH_096C.res = 0, OC_AH_096T.res = 0, 
    OC_AH_100C.res = 0, OC_AH_100C.1.res = 0, OC_AH_100T.res = 0, 
    OC_AH_127C.res = 0, OC_AH_127T.res = 0, OC_AH_133C.res = 0, 
    OC_AH_133T.res = 0, OC_ED_008C.res = 0, OC_ED_008C.1.res = 0, 
    OC_ED_008C.2.res = 0, OC_ED_008C.3.res = 0, OC_ED_008T.res = 0, 
    OC_ED_016C.res = 0, OC_ED_016T.res = 0, OC_ED_031C.res = 0, 
    OC_ED_031T.res = 0, OC_ED_036C.res = 0, OC_ED_036T.res = 0, 
    OC_GS_001C.res = 0, OC_GS_001T.res = 0, OC_QE_062C.res = 0, 
    OC_QE_062T.res = 0, OC_RS_010C.res = 0, OC_RS_010T.res = 0, 
    OC_RS_027C.res = 0, OC_RS_027C.1.res = 0, OC_RS_027C.2.res = 0, 
    OC_RS_027T.res = 0, OC_SH_051C.res = 0, OC_SH_051T.res = 0, 
    OC_ST_014C.res = 0, OC_ST_014C.1.res = 0, OC_ST_014T.res = 0, 
    OC_ST_016T.res = 0, OC_ST_020C.res = 0, OC_ST_020T.res = 0, 
    OC_ST_024C.res = 0, OC_ST_024T.res = 0, OC_ST_033C.res = 0, 
    OC_ST_033T.res = 0, OC_ST_034C.res = 0, OC_ST_034C.1.res = 0, 
    OC_ST_034C.2.res = 0, OC_ST_034T.res = 0, OC_ST_035C.res = 0, 
    OC_ST_035T.res = 0, OC_ST_036C.res = 0, OC_ST_036T.res = 0, 
    OC_ST_037T.res = 0, OC_ST_040C.res = 0, OC_ST_040T.res = 0, 
    OC_WG_001T.res = 0, OC_WG_002C.res = 0, OC_WG_002T.res = 0, 
    OC_WG_005C.res = 0, OC_WG_005T.res = 0, OC_WG_006C.res = 0, 
    OC_WG_006T.res = 0, OC_WG_009T.res = 0, OC_WG_019C.res = 0, 
    OC_WG_019T.res = 0, Means.res = 0, sd.res = 0, ind = 1L), .Names = c("chr", 
"leftPos", "OC_AH_026C.res", "OC_AH_026C.1.res", "OC_AH_026C.2.res", 
"OC_AH_026T.res", "OC_AH_058T.res", "OC_AH_084C.res", "OC_AH_084T.res", 
"OC_AH_086C.res", "OC_AH_086C.1.res", "OC_AH_086C.2.res", "OC_AH_086C.3.res", 
"OC_AH_086T.res", "OC_AH_088C.res", "OC_AH_088T.res", "OC_AH_094C.res", 
"OC_AH_094C.1.res", "OC_AH_094C.2.res", "OC_AH_094C.3.res", "OC_AH_094C.4.res", 
"OC_AH_094C.5.res", "OC_AH_094C.6.res", "OC_AH_094C.7.res", "OC_AH_094T.res", 
"OC_AH_096C.res", "OC_AH_096T.res", "OC_AH_100C.res", "OC_AH_100C.1.res", 
"OC_AH_100T.res", "OC_AH_127C.res", "OC_AH_127T.res", "OC_AH_133C.res", 
"OC_AH_133T.res", "OC_ED_008C.res", "OC_ED_008C.1.res", "OC_ED_008C.2.res", 
"OC_ED_008C.3.res", "OC_ED_008T.res", "OC_ED_016C.res", "OC_ED_016T.res", 
"OC_ED_031C.res", "OC_ED_031T.res", "OC_ED_036C.res", "OC_ED_036T.res", 
"OC_GS_001C.res", "OC_GS_001T.res", "OC_QE_062C.res", "OC_QE_062T.res", 
"OC_RS_010C.res", "OC_RS_010T.res", "OC_RS_027C.res", "OC_RS_027C.1.res", 
"OC_RS_027C.2.res", "OC_RS_027T.res", "OC_SH_051C.res", "OC_SH_051T.res", 
"OC_ST_014C.res", "OC_ST_014C.1.res", "OC_ST_014T.res", "OC_ST_016T.res", 
"OC_ST_020C.res", "OC_ST_020T.res", "OC_ST_024C.res", "OC_ST_024T.res", 
"OC_ST_033C.res", "OC_ST_033T.res", "OC_ST_034C.res", "OC_ST_034C.1.res", 
"OC_ST_034C.2.res", "OC_ST_034T.res", "OC_ST_035C.res", "OC_ST_035T.res", 
"OC_ST_036C.res", "OC_ST_036T.res", "OC_ST_037T.res", "OC_ST_040C.res", 
"OC_ST_040T.res", "OC_WG_001T.res", "OC_WG_002C.res", "OC_WG_002T.res", 
"OC_WG_005C.res", "OC_WG_005T.res", "OC_WG_006C.res", "OC_WG_006T.res", 
"OC_WG_009T.res", "OC_WG_019C.res", "OC_WG_019T.res", "Means.res", 
"sd.res", "ind"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x103006f78>)
```

For each column I would like to keep the value as it is if it agrees with the row above it for that chr, only if that value is 1 or -1. If there is no agreement I'd like to convert the value to zero.

For example (not using the dput above)

```
chr       leftPos     OC_030_ST.res
1           4324            0
1           23433           1
1           34436           1
1           64755           1
3           234             1
3           354             0
4           1666            0
4           4565            0
5           34777           1
7           2345            1
7           4567            1
```

should become

```
 chr       leftPos     OC_030_ST.res
1           4324            0
1           23433           1
1           34436           1
1           64755           1
3           234             0
3           354             0
4           1666            0
4           4565            0
5           34777           0
7           2345            1
7           4567            1
```

I had a dataframe (called Final) once upon a time that had a column called Def that contained all the res values in one column so I could do something like

```
ContZ<-setDT(Final)[,ind:=rleid(Def)][, if(.N>1) .SD, .(chr, ind)][, ind:=NULL][]
```

but assuming I'm going to need apply I'm not sure how to use this.

I tried:

```
MeOut<-lapply(df_list2res,function (col){
  ContZ<-setDT(df_list2res)[,ind:=rleid(col)][, if(.N>1) .SD, .(chr, ind)][, ind:=NULL][]
})
```

but I get the error when I try to `View(MeOut)` that

```
Error in View : arguments imply differing number of rows:
```

I suspect this is because I have been getting rid of rows rather than replacing values although I can't be sure....

Answer (score 0):

Here's your simple example in dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)

#create a simple version of your df
df<- data.frame(c(1,1,1,1,3,3,4,4,5,7,7),c(0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1))                                          
names(df) <- c("chr","OC_030_ST.res")

df2 <- df%>%
  mutate(last=lag(chr))%>%
  mutate(OC_030_ST.res =ifelse(chr == last | is.na(last),
                   ifelse(OC_030_ST.res == 1|OC_030_ST.res == -1,OC_030_ST.res,0),0))%>%
  select(-last)
df2
```

The logic here is that if the chr value one behind the current value equals the last *and* the 'OC_030_ST.res' value is 1 or -1, the value will be retained. In all other cases, the value is reset to 0. Please let me know if this isn't the logic you intended.

Note, the first item is a special case (as there can't be a lag on the first row), hence the is.na(last) check catches this.

edit:  I realised you may want to apply this to multiple columns in your data frame. The below will let you do this

```
df<- data.frame(c(1,1,1,1,3,3,4,4,5,7,7),c(0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1),c(0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1))                                          
names(df) <- c("chr","OC_030_ST.res","OC_031_ST.res")

df$count<-1:nrow(df)


make0 <- function(x) {ifelse(x == 1 | x == -1, x <-0, x <- x)}
dftemp <- df%>%
  mutate(last=lag(chr))%>%
  mutate(flag=ifelse(chr == last | is.na(last),0,1))%>%
  dplyr::filter(flag==1)%>%
  #the below column range will need to be changed to the columns you actually need to change
  mutate_each(funs(make0),2:3)%>%
  select(-c(flag,last))
dftemp

#update the original dataframe with the modified values
df[match(dftemp$count, df$count), ] <- dftemp
df <- subset(df,select=-count)
df
```

Comment: Hi. It doesnt seem to isolating the more than one row in agreement rows and resetting the rest to zero. I'm not sure why. What further information would you need

Comment: Sorry, I spotted an error in my code. Can you check this now to see if it gives you the response you need?

Comment: Hi was it the top sample that had the error or the bottom. I don't think the bottom one has changed- that's the one I'm trying to use

Comment: I changed the top one according to the bottom, but still lots of columns where 1 is on its own surrounded by a sea of zeros.... Shall I give you a better example dataset?